# How to add a changeable icon to component in storybook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, storybook

I have a component - a simple list with an icon, header and links. I need to add an icon in front of the header. So that you can choose which icon will be in the Storybook. I can't find it in the documentation. And I can't figure out how to do it. If you know how, please help me.

```
// ItemsList.tsx 
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { myIcon1 } from 'src/icons/Icon1';
import { myIcon2 } from 'src/icons/Icon2';

interface ItemsList {
  icon: ReactElement;
  header: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

export const ItemsList = ({ icon, header, children }: ItemsList) => (
  <div>
    {icon} // Have no idea how to add one of imported icons here??
    <div>{header}</div>
    <ul>{children}</ul>
  </div>
);
```

My Story File:

```
// ItemsList.story.jsx
import { ItemsList } from './itemsList';

export default {
  title: 'ItemsList',
  component: ItemsList,
  argTypes: {
    icon: {
      control: { type: 'radio', options: ['no icon', 'icon 1', 'icon 2'] },
    },
    header: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultValue: 'Header',
    },
    children: {
      type: 'array',
      name: 'label',
      defaultValue: ['link 1', 'link 2', 'link 3'],
    },
  },
};

const Template = (args) => <ItemsList {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});

Default.args = {
  icon: ????,
  header: 'Header',
  children: ['link 1', 'link 2', 'link 3'],
};
```

Comment: Maybe with a rsuite or react-dropdown? just as you would select anything else. sadly i got no specific example so just a suggestion

Comment: Thanks, It's not about how to select - that's a simple deal. It's about how to add a set of svg icons to a component in the Storybook.